# Error Handling MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi what I am trying to achieve is saving a record from a form with error handling:

- MSGBOX "Success! Do you want to add a new record?" [Yes/No] form is saved.
- New record, clear field Me.Serial
- MSGBOX "Something went wrong, please complete relevant fields"

What i have tried so far is:

```
On Error GoTo Err_cmdCloseForm_Click8
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
MsgBox "item successfully checked out"
DoCmd.Close

Exit_cmdCloseForm_Click:
 Exit Sub

Err_cmdCloseForm_Click8:
 MsgBox "Save was unsuccessful, please try again", vbInformation, "Warning"
 Resume Exit_cmdCloseForm_Click
```

Field [Serial] is required, yet when i click save with no information entered into any field i receive a success message. Any thoughts or links would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

J

Comment: Access default is to save, you have to do quite a lot to prevent a save. You should post the event(s) you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use the BeforeUpdate event to validate and possibly to prevent an update, and the AfterUpdate event to display a confirming message.